# PeerJs File-Transfer is too slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

I created a react application, through which we can transfer files from one system to another using peerjs, but file transfer speed for android devices is too slow.

Below are the codes I used to send and receive data

```
useEffect(() => {
    var peer = new Peer();
    peer.on("open", function (id) {
      console.log(id);
    });
    peerRef.current = peer;
  }, []);

  const sendFiles = () => {
    var conn = peerRef.current.connect(`${receiverId}`);
    if (files != null) {
      conn.on("open", () => {
        for (let j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
          const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // In bytes
          const chunks = Math.ceil(files[j].size / chunkSize);
          console.log(files[j].size);
          var pro = 0;
          for (let i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
            const offset = i * chunkSize;
            pro = ((i + 1) / chunks) * 100;
            setProgress(pro);
            conn.send({
              file: files[j].slice(offset, offset + chunkSize),
              name: files[j].name,
              size: files[j].size,
              type: "file",
              progress: ((i + 1) / chunks) * 100,
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }

  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    var peer = new Peer();

    peer.on("open", function (id) {
      setReceiverID(id);
      console.log(id);
    });

    peer.on("connection", (conn) => {
      var chunk = [];
      conn.on("data", (data) => {
        if (data) {
          setReceiving(true);
        }
        chunk = [...chunk, data.file];
        setProgress(data.progress);
        if (data.progress == 100) {
          console.log(data);
          combineTheChunks(chunk);
          chunk = [];
          setProgress(0);
          setReceivedName((prevname) => [...prevname, data.name]);
        }

        
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

In this project I'm receiving ids of each other with the help of qr codes